# CountDownTimer not stopping or restarting

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to set up dailyReward system, and I'm almost finished but I do have some problems with the CountDownTimer. So when the Timer gets to 0, and you tap on the claimReward, you get the reward and the timers should start again counting down. But the problem is; it does count Minus up, if you restart the app it gets to normal.

This is the countingdown method, whatever I put in the onFinish() nothing happens

```
    public void loadDailyRewardCountDown() {

        CountDown = true;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setLenient(false);

        String endTime = getDailyRewardsDate;

        Date endDate;
        Date startDate;
        long milliseconds = 0;
        long millisec = 0;
        try {
            endDate = formatter.parse(endTime);
            startDate = formatter.parse(curDate);
            millisec = startDate.getTime();
            milliseconds = endDate.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long startTime = millisec;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                //startTime = startTime - 1;
                Long serverUptimeSeconds =
                        (millisUntilFinished - startTime) / 1000;

                //String daysLeft = String.format("%d", serverUptimeSeconds / 86400);
                //txtViewDays.setText(daysLeft);

                String hoursLeft = String.format("%d", (serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600);
                if (hoursLeft.equals("0")) {
                    tv_hour.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    tv_hour.setText(hoursLeft + " H");
                }

                String minutesLeft = String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
                if (minutesLeft.equals("0")) {
                    tv_minutes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (hoursLeft.equals("0")) {
                    tv_minutes.setText(minutesLeft + " Min");
                } else {
                    tv_minutes.setText(minutesLeft + " M");
                }

                String secondsLeft = String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
                if (hoursLeft.equals("0") && minutesLeft.equals("0")) {
                    tv_seconds.setText(secondsLeft + " Seconds");
                } else {
                    tv_seconds.setText(secondsLeft);
                }
                if (hoursLeft.equals("0") && minutesLeft.equals("0") && secondsLeft.equals("0")){
                    Toast.makeText(DashBoardActivity.this, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    GetCurDate();
                    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                    layout_countdown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_claim_daily_reward.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

and in the button that you have to tap to claim reward, I just call the loadDailyRewardCountDown and CountDown boolean to false.

Answer (score 0):

An easier and more maintainable approach would be to save the time your user first starts your app in the [`Shared Preferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) and then every time the user starts the app again, it is checked if 24 hours have passed since the last startup and if so, the new time is saved.

Then you can use your `CountDownTimer` if the user happens to use the App while the 24 hours elapse and simply stop the timer after he is entitled to claim his reward because the user wont use the App for 24 hours straight.